# Empty Text box conformation <Ok> or <Cancle>.If It is Ok do something else reject the application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below message box in asp.net web application. Now i want to convert this message box as a confirmation message box and do something when it is true else means reject the application.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "confirm('Address,Phone Number,Email ID Is Empty Do You Want To Continue');", true);
```

Comment: This is client side confirmation box so you will have to do this on client side via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }

}
</script>

</body>
```

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx